# how to extract the 3 highest values from each year in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DF with a lot of rows, and and this data basically is divided by year.

To make the explanation more direct, I will give an example. Let's assume this database
[image]

I want to have a new df with the two (or three) highest values from each year and with the all columns below, just filter the rows based on this condition

Comment: `df.groupby('Year').apply(lambda g: g.nlargest(2, 'Value'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group on `Year` and then select using `nlargest`. Using a simple example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Year' : [2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023],
                  'Value' : [3, 14, 15, 6, 4, 12, 11, 4],
                   'Name' : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
                  })

df2 = df.loc[df.groupby('Year', group_keys = False)['Value'].nlargest(2).index].reset_index(drop = True)

print(df2)
```

gives:

```
   Year  Value Name
0  2022     15    C
1  2022     14    B
2  2023     12    F
3  2023     11    G
```